# Why isn't the from address included in a transaction?

Tags: transactions, balances

Building transactions with [ethereumjs-tx](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx#usage) and I'm confused as to why the from address is not included in the transaction. The transaction parameters are:

• nonce - transaction nonce

• gasPrice

• gasLimit

• to - to Address

• value - amount to be sent

• data

• chainId - EIP 155 chainId - mainnet: 1, ropsten: 3

And the private key is used to sign the constructed transaction. But how does the ethereum network know from who to deduct the money from?

Answer (score 1):

Each transactions is signed, and the signature includes enough information to determine who signed it.

Comment: How though? What if the user is using an HD wallet which has many addresses (aka accounts) for a single private key? How does the network know from which account to deduct the balance from? What if they are both on the same transaction nonce number as well?

Comment: An HD wallet uses a seed to generate many accounts. Each account has its own private key. The transaction is signed with one of those private keys, which uniquely identifies the address of the account.

Comment: So you're saying you don't sign the transaction with the master private key in ethereum? But instead with the private key of the address node? In which case (a bit off topic sorry!) the master private key is only useful for recreating the HD wallet tree and is not useful for signing?

Comment: That's correct. See https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki if you want all the gory details.